# Codeception Acceptance test tries to check database for populated data

Tags: php, testing, codeception, acceptance-testing

I'm trying to create a few acceptance tests which use a repopulating dump after each test like described here https://codeception.com/docs/09-Data and here https://codeception.com/docs/modules/Db.

Somehow i looks like i didn't get the idea of the cleanup/population concept.

I tried to populate the database with a simple table and a few rows and check within a simple test if these rows exist, but looks like no data exists even if the report shows the database has been populated.

composer.json

```
{
    "name": "tests",
    "description": "654321",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "require-dev": {
        "codeception/codeception": "~4.0",
        "codeception/module-asserts": "^1.0",
        "codeception/module-webdriver": "^1.0",
        "codeception/module-phpbrowser": "^1.0",
        "codeception/module-filesystem": "^1.0",
        "codeception/module-db": "^1.0"
    }
}
```

Codecepion DB Module

```
modules:
  enabled: [Db]
  config:
    Db:
      dsn: "mysql:host=%HOST%;dbname=%DBNAME%;charset=utf8"
      user: "root"
      password: "root"
      dump: "tests/codeception/_data/dump.sql"
      populate: true
      cleanup: true
      populator: "mysql -u$user -p$password $dbname < $dump"
```

dump.sql

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `my_table`;
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `my_table` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'CA_A'),
(2, 'CA_B'),
(3, 'CA_C');
```

Acceptance Test

```
public function exampleTest(\AcceptanceTester $I)
{
    $item = $I->grabFromDatabase('my_table', 'name', ['id' => 1]);
    var_dump($item);
    $I->seeInDatabase('my_table', array('id' => 2,'name' => 'CA_B'));
}
```

Report

```
Run php vendor/bin/codecept run "tests/codeception/acceptance/mytest.php:exampleTest" -vvv --html --fail-fast
Codeception PHP Testing Framework v4.1.21
Powered by PHPUnit 8.5.17 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

  [Connecting To Db] {"config":{"populate":true,"cleanup":true,"reconnect":false,"waitlock":0,"dump":"tests/codeception/_data/dump.sql","populator":"mysql -u$user -p$password $dbname < $dump","dsn":"mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=test;charset=utf8","user":"root","password":"root"},"options":[]}
  [Db] Connected to default test
  Rebuilding AcceptanceTester...
  [Db] Executing Populator: `mysql -uroot -proot test < tests/codeception/_data/dump.sql`
  [Db] Populator Finished.

Acceptance Tests (1) ---------------------------------------
Modules: Asserts, \Helper\Acceptance, DbHelper, Filesystem, MailCatcher, Db
------------------------------------------------------------
  Printing HTML report into report.html
mytest: example Test
Signature: mytest.php:exampleTest
Test: tests/codeception/acceptance/mytest.php:exampleTest
Scenario --
  [Db] Executing Populator: `mysql -uroot -proot test < tests/codeception/_data/dump.sql`
  [Db] Populator Finished.
 I grab from database "my_table","name",{"id":1}
  [Query] SELECT name FROM `my_table` WHERE `id` = ? 
  [Parameters] [1]
bool(false)
 I see in database "my_table",{"id":2,"name":"C...}
  [Query] SELECT count(*) FROM `my_table` WHERE `id` = ? AND `name` = ? 
  [Parameters] [2,"CA_B"]
  Screenshot and page source were saved into '/home/runner/work/something/tests/codeception/_output/' dir
 FAIL 

------------------------------------------------------------


Time: 1.08 seconds, Memory: 14.00 MB

There was 1 failure:

---------
1) mytest: example Test
 Test  tests/codeception/acceptance/install/mytest.php:exampleTest
 Step  See in database "my_table",{"id":2,"name":"CA_B"}
 Fail  No matching records found for criteria {"id":2,"name":"CA_B"} in table my_table
Failed asserting that 0 is greater than 0.
```

Comment: Didn't you forget to commit transaction in a dump?

Comment: Jesus, I should call it a day. Thanks.